# Making use of polymorphism in a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression, extension-methods

### The problem

I have an extension method that extends `IEnumerable<T>` and takes an `Expression` that navigates to a property which itself must be `IEnumerable`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Identify a child collection to search on
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source">source data on which to search</param>
/// <param name="property">Enumerable properties to search.</param>
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Search<TSource, TProperty>(
                             this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                             Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TProperty>> property)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

The above works well when the child property is defined as `IEnumerable<T>` and can be called as follows:

```
var result = shops.Search(s => s.ProductEnumerable);
```

however **it currently does not find this method if the child property is `ICollection<T>`, `IList<T>` or anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`**

Another key point is that I want to be able to use the method without defining the types explicitly.

```
var result = shops.Search(s => s.ProductList);    
//NOT
var result = shops.Search<Shop, Product>(s => s.ProductList);
```

---

### What I have tried

#### Attempt 1

I thought I could possibly create a new generic (`TCollection`) and put a constraint on that where `TCollection` is `IEnumerable<TProperty>`.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Search<TSource, TCollection, TProperty>(
                             this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                             Expression<Func<TSource, TCollection>> property)
    where TCollection : IEnumerable<TProperty>
```

This failed as the code was no longer able to locate the method.

#### Attempt 2

I then thought that I could make the entire second parameter a generic and put the correct contraints on that.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Search<TSource, TCollection, TProperty>(
                             this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                             TCollection property) 
    where TCollection : Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TProperty>>
```

This also failed with the following error:

> Cannot use sealed class `Expression<TDelegate>` as type parameter constraint.

---

**Is there a way of achieving what I desire or do I simply need to create overloads for all the interfaces that implement IEnumerable???**

Thanks in advance for taking the tine to read this lengthy description

Comment: What is `Search` method supposed to do?

Comment: When you say `however it currently does not find this method if the child property is...` can you elaborate on what you mean? As the answer below demonstrates, it's not clear what problem you're actually having.

Comment: Good question.... having looked at the code again, when I change the property to `ICollection` I receive a error message which told me that the problem was that it is trying to use a different overload of `Search`.  I'll update my question.  Thank you

Comment: `ICollection` does not inherit `IEnumerable<T>` - you'll certainly need a different overload for *non generic* types.

Comment: `ICollection<T>` does - [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx).  The comments and answers here have realised my true issue so I will try and fix that myself however I may well create a new question if I am unable to solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm, no, the code you're showing works just fine. The problem must be in how you use that `IEnumerable<TProperty>` in your search method - remember, since it's a return value in the `Func`, it *must* be covariant.

Actual compilable piece of code:

```
void Main()
{
  var enumerable = default(IEnumerable<MyItem>);

  Search(enumerable, i => i.MyEnumerable);
  Search(enumerable, i => i.MyCollection);
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> Search<TSource, TProperty>
  (
    IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> property)
{
    return null;
}

public class MyItem
{
  public IEnumerable<string> MyEnumerable { get; set; }
  public ICollection<string> MyCollection { get; set; }
}
```

There's no error during compilation *or* runtime.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion by [mocking out the code](http://rextester.com/IIN74892)

Comment: Hmmmm.. thanks for the response.  Let me see what differs between yours and mine....! +1

Comment: Thank you for this.  This made me realise that it wasn't this part of the code that was the problem.  The problem exists because of another conflicting overload.

Comment: @Jamiec - this is a [mock of my actual problem](http://rextester.com/LHX46187).  The problem is that an overload that is restricted to structs is being called not the one for `IEnumerable`'s

Comment: @NinjaNye - the only option I can see (and its not very nice) is to cast the result: http://rextester.com/WOHNFR50421

Comment: @NinjaNye Okay, that makes sense. C#'s generics are very limited in this way - overloads in particular are quite tricky. Simplifying, there is *no* overload resolution based on type constraints. So the overload resolution is done ignoring the type constraints, which means that `TProperty` is a better fit than `IEnumerable<TProperty>` (following usual overload resolution rules). This is easily seen if you remove the type constraint - the code compiles, but it's the second overload that's called. You might think that `IEnumerable<TProperty>` is the better choice, but it's worse in other cases.

Comment: @NinjaNye In the end, I think you have two options - one, you could make one global method that would do the overload resolution dynamically, using your rules. A simple `if (property.Type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))` should work fine. Of course, you lose some of the compile-time niceties, but that can't be really avoided (`dynamic` is very helpful to avoid using reflection inefficiently). Two, use different names for the different methods - depending on your exact scenario, this might be a preferred solution anyway.

Comment: Your right. I don't think the global option is gonna fly since the returned types do differ. Think I'm going to have to change the name to become something like `SearchChildrenOf`. Thanks for all your help, including going the extra mile once I discovered my true issue.